# @Query(value="select * from function()") vs SimpleJdbcCall Spring Data JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying to call function with returned data by annotation Query. And receive exception.

my function:
[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsSWX.png)

I'm create interface repository implements CrudRepository<User, String>, and create a method:
[call function in repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMW95.png)

After call this method i receive exception "The result is returned when it was not expected", at the same time data was added to table.

I chose a different path and Create bean DataSource, then add method to service class where were create SimpleJdbcCall with returned value boolean add param to Map<String, Object>. After that executeFunction(Boolean.TYPE, param). As a result I recieve TRUE without any exception.

Maybe someone knows how call function with returned value from annotation @Query in this case?

a small clarification:

- the table we are writing to has no id. Primary key is a first field whith name "one".
- Database is PostgreSql.
- use latest driver postrgeSql (dependency version 42.6.0)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I decided it. For data jdbc call function necessary don't use annotation @Modifying.

Comment: Please post your code. Without it, the question is basically unanswerable.

Comment: @JensSchauder I added code by screenshot. I trying to add completely code, but it he looked disappointed.

Comment: you can't select FROM a function returning a scalar value: a scalar function can appear in the SELECT column list or the WHERE, not in the FROM.

Comment: @p3consulting, Hi. Thanks, a lot. However, when I'm making "select from function" or "select function" I have receive result of function.
Actually. my question was about how to call function use Data Jdbc with annotation, and without SimpleJdbc.

Comment: make your function (or make another one if you need both versions) returns a "table of boolean" instead of a scalar boolean.

Comment: Your decision has the right to life! Thanks, a lot ))